# MVC Equivalent of button click event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

MVC5 EF6

I've started an MVC app and all is going well - create/edit/delete views all working well.

I've come to a point where the "standard" @Html.TextBoxFor/@Html.EditorFor etc does do what I need.

I'm creating a Product that has a Category. There are about 10 Parent Categories and each can have multiple children, and each child can have multiple children etc. etc. so the standard controls don't give a good user experience - the scaffolded code has a combo box.

I've implemented a modal that displays all categories in a "treeview" - it's actually nested `<ul></ul>`. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/umutc1/eyf9q87c/ but I have a button at each treenode and the tree is generated on the fly:

```
@helper TreeView(ICollection<Heisenberg.Models.Category> categoryTree)
{
foreach (var item in categoryTree)
{
    <li>
        @if (item.Category1.Count > 0)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(@item.CategoryID.ToString(), "SelectCategory", new { id = @item.CategoryID })

            <ul>
                @TreeView(item.Category1)
            </ul>
        }
        else
        {

            @Html.ActionLink(@item.CategoryID.ToString(), "SelectCategory", new { id = @item.CategoryID })

        }
    </li>
}
}
```

So far so good. The issue I have, and can't get my head around as I'm new to MVC - How to code so that when the user clicks the button, the Model is updated to contain the CategoryID.

As you can see, instead of a standard button, I've used an ActionLink and in my controller I have this:

```
    public ActionResult SelectCategory([Bind(Include = "ProdID,CategoryID")] Product product, int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        product.CategoryID = id.GetValueOrDefault();

        return View(product);
    }
```

This obviously doesn't work. The categoryID comes through ok but the `return View(product);` errors out - it's trying to send me to http://localhost:61217/Products/SelectCategory/163 which doesn't exit, I just want to return to the Product Create page with the Product Model containing the CategoryID I have just selected.

Am I on the right tracks for the equivalent of asp button click event? Or should I be doing this completely different?

Comment: You action links only pass a parameter `id` to the method, so it should be just `public ActionResult SelectCategory(int id)`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a new Product with the specified category, in which case your links should point to a method (say) `public ActionResult Create(int id)` on `ProductController`, where you initialize a new `Product`, set the category based on the `id` parameter and then return the view for creating a new `Product`, so the links would be `@Html.ActionLink(@item.CategoryID.ToString(), "Create", "Product", new { id = @item.CategoryID }, null)`

Comment: Thanks. OK let me give that a try. I'm already on the Create Product page at this point though - wouldn't this "abandon" that product, and any other data i've entered, e.g. title, and open a new page?

Comment: If that's the case, why are you even calling a controller method? If you on the Product Create page, then all you need to do is assign the selected category to a control in the form.

Comment: Ok, like I said, I'm new to this. In asp I'd do this in the button click event, but MVC doesn't have this. I thought perhaps this type of thing went in the controller, obviously not. So could you please show me an example of how to create buttons linked to each Category that once clicked will set the CategoryID in the Product Model? Or, as you say will set the value of e.g. A text box that's linked to the model?

Comment: For that you will need javascipt/jquery - you don't really need links at all. You need to store the categories `id` value an associated element - `data-id="@item.CategoryID"` and then handle the elements `.click()` event, retrieve the value - `var id = $(this).data('id');` and assign it to whatever control you have associated with the category proprty. You have not shown you model or view so can't be more specific. However you may be interested in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768069/MVC-Custom-Select-Control)

Comment: Hmmm, ok I'll give it a shot.. It all makes sense. I wanted to avoid JavaScript but if that's the way it's done I'll try it. Just in work now and this is a private project so I'll get back to you later to say how I've got on. Cheers.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your help with this - and sorry for the delay replying - i managed to resolve my issue using your recommendations. I've added the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StephenMuecke I managed to solve this.

Here's what I did:
On my Create page I had a HiddenField for the CategoryID

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "tbCategoryID" })
```

and a textbox to put the category name once selected - this isn't required but is good for user feedback that they've actually selected a category:

```
@Html.TextBox("CategoryName", null, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "tbCategoryName", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Every node of my treeview/nested `<li>` has a `<span>` with class `category` and the data-id and data-categoryname attributes to store these details for use later.

```
<span class="leaf closemodal category" data-id="@item.CategoryID" data-categoryname="@item.CategoryName"> @item.CategoryName</span>
```

I then used Javascript to add an onclick function to these `<span>`:

```
$('span.category').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                var name = $(this).data('categoryname');
                $('#tbCategoryID').val(id);
                $('#tbCategoryName').val(name);
            });
```

Adding this click function means that when a user clicks one of the `<span>` it gets the id and the name from the `data-XXX` attributes of the span. The function then adds the ID and NAME to the appropriate fields - the HiddenField and the textBox.

Upon form submit, the Category ID is posted back to the Controller.